# Google Oauth2 login with Scala throws exception with .setAccessType("offline")

Tags: scala, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, google-oauth

I'm trying to get a refresh token to bulk upload files to Google Drive. It works for 'online' access using this code:

```
      val flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
      httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
      .setApprovalPrompt("auto")
      .setAccessType("online")
      .build
```

But when I change to:

```
setAccessType("offline")
```

This exception is thrown:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please use the Builder and call setJsonFactory, setTransport and setClientSecrets
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:92)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:49)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.setRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:221)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.setRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:158)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.setFromTokenResponse(Credential.java:540)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.setFromTokenResponse(GoogleCredential.java:240)
at google_uploader2$.delayedEndpoint$google_uploader2$1(google_uploader2.scala:82)
at google_uploader2$delayedInit$body.apply(google_uploader2.scala:1)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at google_uploader2$.main(google_uploader2.scala:1)
at google_uploader2.main(google_uploader2.scala)
```

I really can't track this down and any suggestions are appreciated. I've tried `.setApprovalPrompt("force")`.

Thanks, Clyde

Comment: Thanks, Bubletan. I'll try to be less sloppy next time.

Comment: have you tried doing what the error message says?

Comment: pinoyyid- Yes, although it looks to me like those are supplied to the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder constructor as arguments. And as I mentioned it does work perfectly for 'online' access. The problem is I don't receive a refresh token.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code. I just tried running the java sample code from the Google API docs and it throws the same exception. I'm thinking this has something to do with the application as it exists on the Google Developer's Console, but I haven't found anything that looks like it would be related.

Comment: it's worth posting your code that implements the advice from the error message just to eliminate it. Also, you realise that the refresh token is only returned on the first request. If this user is already authed, it might be worth revoking the auth to force a token,

Comment: I looked at the source  for the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder and the syntax of the constructor is exactly as above. I will have to recreate what i did to implement the advice from the error message. And yes, I did revoke the authorization a couple of times to test if that was the problem.